# Table for all companies

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I need my conversion table (we integrate data from other system where their values mean another thing in our AX instance) to be encompassing all companies.

When I deploy the project, I'll upload that table's data through an Excel import but I don't want to do it for all 5 of our companies.

I know when code runs as Admin, it fetches data from tables regardless of company (unless you specify so in the `where` clause) but I want standard users to see the table's data regardless of the company they are in when **they** run the code.

Is this possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the table's SaveDataPerCompany property set to Yes (default)? If so, I would just change that to No, which will cause the table to not have the dataAreaId column. Such tables should be accessible from all companies.

Comment: If it works for you, let me know and I'll convert to an answer.

Comment: @kingofzeal I guess that kind of "works" but when doing this, you lose the ability to load data via Excel import. So that's not a solution that for me at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there s a property on tables called SaveDataPerCompany.  The default is yes but if you change it to no, then essentially the DataAreaId field is no longer applicable and the same data will be seen in all companies.  You change the property by finding the table in the AOT (e.g Data Dictionary > Tables) and right-clicking it and choosing Properties towards the bottom.